# Why consider an accelerating frame instead of a stationary frame for the Special Theory of Relativity?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electric-fields

According to Special theory of **relativity**, magnetic field is equal to electric field if we see it in a frame of electron (in the frame of electron) but why we have to see it in **accelerating frame**?
 Why can't we just see in **stationary frame**?

Comment: Just look how it is derived.

Comment: "a magnetic field transforms into an electric field" is not the same thing as "magnetic field is equal to/the same as electric field." Look at the special relativity equations for how electric and magnetic fields transform under Lorentz boosts, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Who wrote that the frame of the electron is accelerated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnetic field is always a zero-divergence vector field (since there are no isolated magnetic monopoles). The electric field has nonzero divergence when there is a charge distribution.

So, the magnetic field is not “equal” to the electric field.
Instead, the magnetic field and the electric field are components of a more complicated object (the field tensor).

(For another distinction, the electric field is an ordinary polar vector, whereas the magnetic field is a pseudo vector. Again, they are not equal.)

Answer (score 0):

In special relativity, when you're moving at a significant fraction of the speed of light, the way you see electric and magnetic fields changes.
 This happens due to how space and time behave at **high speeds**. Electric and magnetic fields can appear mixed up and similar to each other from your moving perspective, even though they're distinct in a stationary frame. This phenomenon is known as "**relativistic aberration**," and it's not about acceleration but rather about how things look when you're moving very fast.

So, yes, we can just see them in a stationary frame as separate entities.

Answer (score 0):

I actually saw an answer on quora that is -
"You may know that things with a relative velocity will appear to be contracted along their axis of motion. This is called length contraction. It's so small at everyday speeds that we don't notice it, but it becomes apparent at appreciable fractions of the speed of light.

If you have a line of charge of linear charge density λ and move it at a velocity in the direction of its length, it will appear to be contracted. Then it will have an apparently higher charge density equal to γλ, where γ is the Lorentz factor, equal to  1/√(1−v2
/c2)
.

From Gauss's law, we know that a higher linear charge density will have a higher electric field. This increased electric field due to a relative velocity is the magnetic field.

This is what happens with charges in a current-carrying wire. Although the electrons are moving very slowly (centimeters per minute I believe), there are so many charges in a wire that this relativistic effect is very noticeable"